# Is there enough pressure to trigger an implosion type nuclear fission weapon at the bottom of Mariana's trench?

Tags: pressure, nuclear-physics, water, estimation

Is there enough forces from water pressure to trigger an implosion type nuclear fission weapon if it was placed at the bottom of Mariana's trench without using any implosives? Would the blast be less or more powerful than the same weapon triggered at sea level using implosives?

Comment: As it's homework, **you** can make a rough estimate :). Find out how what 50kg of TNT yields in joules during an explosion, which is roughly the amount of trigger material,  ( probably much less) then convert 1,800 atmospheres of pressure (depth of trench) to energy, (pressure goes to energy over volume). I can tell you that there has been a nuclear bomb on the seafloor 5,000m down in the sea off Japan for the last 60 years. The trench is 11,000 m in depth.

Comment: http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Teller.html

Comment: I wish we had interesting physics problems like this for homework when I was in school.  I was just curious as to what would happen.

Comment: @Count bliss.  Thanks for the link, but I wanted to know about fission type weapons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bulk_modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) of a material  tells you how much it is compressed by increased pressure. The modulus of Uranium is similar to that of steel, which you will find in the Wiki article. If you do the math you will find that it is compressed by a very small percentage, not enough to trigger reactions.